# Javascript split the string with patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

String:

```
Q$: any character, number goes here.
A$: Answer goes here
C$: c,c1,c2,c3
```

I want the final output as follows

```
  [Q$:=any character, number goes here.,
   A$:=Answer goes here,
   C$:=c,c1,c2,c3
  ]
```

If there are more than one string, then array should have all the values.

Eg:

```
String:

Q$: any character, number goes here.
A$: Answer goes here
C$: c,c1,c2,c3

Q$: any character, number goes here.A$: Answer goes here
C$: c,c1,c2,c3

Q$: any character, number goes here.    A$: Answer goes here

Q$: any character, number goes here.
A$: Answer goes here
C$: c,c1,c2
```

Final array should have all the items as an array to validate.

I have tried

```js
$(function() {
  var y = Array();
  str = `Q$:ADD A GOOD QUESTION
A$:ANSWER
C$:choice0, choice1, choice2, choice2`;

  str.replace(/([ACQ]\$:[\S]*)(.*)/gmi, function(match, p1, p2) {
    y.push([p1, p2]);
  });

  console.log(y);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am missing something. It works in few cases. In few it doesn't. Any suggestions to split them out.

Comment: your output is not valid JS Array/Object, please update it correctly, only then I can help

Comment: Also your eg String, missed 3d C$ for 3rd Q$

Comment: will order of Q$,A$,C$ always same??

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood, as per your requirement, and assuming your output as a valid JSON object, Assuming order of Q$,A$,C$ will be always same, try this code

```
var str = "Your String"
//Add LineBreaks for making a valid format to make our search easier
var formattedOutput = str.replace(/[ACQ]\$/gm, function($0) {
    return "\n" + $0
})

//Split with all LineBreaks
var arr = formattedOutput.trim().split(/\n+/)

var res = [];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    if(arr[i].indexOf("Q$") != -1) {
        res.push({
            "Q$":arr[i].trim().split(/Q\$:\s+/)[1]
        })
    } else {
        if(arr[i].indexOf("A$") != -1) {
console.log(arr[i].trim().split(/A\$:\s+/))
            res[res.length-1]["A$"] = arr[i].trim().split(/A\$:\s+/)[1]
        } else if(arr[i].indexOf("C$") != -1) {
            res[res.length-1]["C$"] = arr[i].trim().split(/C\$:\s+/)[1]
        }
    }
}
console.log(res)
```

```js
var str = $("#test").val()
//Add LineBreaks for making a valid format to make our search easier
var formattedOutput = str.replace(/[ACQ]\$/gm, function($0) {
 return "\n" + $0
})

//Split with all LineBreaks
var arr = formattedOutput.trim().split(/\n+/)

var res = [];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
 if(arr[i].indexOf("Q$") != -1) {
  res.push({
   "Q$":arr[i].trim().split(/Q\$:\s+/)[1]
  })
 } else {
  if(arr[i].indexOf("A$") != -1) {
   res[res.length-1]["A$"] = arr[i].trim().split(/A\$:\s+/)[1]
  } else if(arr[i].indexOf("C$") != -1) {
   res[res.length-1]["C$"] = arr[i].trim().split(/C\$:\s+/)[1]
  }
 }
}

$("#output").html(JSON.stringify(res))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="test" rows="10" tabindex="3">
  Q$: any character, number goes here. A$: Answer goes here C$: c,c1,c2,c3 Q$: any character, number goes here.A$: Answer goes here C$: c,c1,c2,c3 Q$: any character, number goes here. A$: Answer goes here Q$: any character, number goes here. A$: Answer
  goes here C$: c,c1,c2
</textarea>
<div>
  <span id="output"></span>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harpreetsingh/7f6240to/2/)